Array instanced object keeping the same index in Geometry Nodes
In Geometry Nodes, how can I make each group of balls have the same random color pattern repeated nine times? I want to generate an array of equal 3x3 combinations but unfortunately the instances are shuffled for each of the nine instances.


You need to add a random value to the the spheres before instancing them on the main grid:

And in the shader, you use an "Attribute" node to get this value, with an important setting: it must be set to "instancer", otherwise you will need to "realize instances" in the geometry nodes:


Thank you so much Daniel! That's just what I was looking for.

Hello, @Sergio, welcome to stack exchange.
When an answer solves your problem, please mark it as answered so the community knows.

Ok, fine. I can't find the "mark as answered" button.

@Sergio, it's the green check on the left side of the answer
